# How to deploy custom nginx app on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to deploy a custom nginx app on my kubernetes cluster.

I have three raspberry in a cluster. My deplotment file looks as follows

```
kubepodDeploy.yaml

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image:   privateRepo/my-nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort 
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
```

How can I deploy it so that I can access my app by ipadress. Which service type do I need?

my service details are:

```
kubectl describe service my-nginx                                                                                                                           ~/Project/htmlBasic
Name:                     my-nginx
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=my-nginx
Annotations:              Selector:  run=my-nginx
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.99.107.194
Port:                     http  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30488/TCP
Endpoints:                10.32.0.4:80,10.32.0.5:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  32430/TCP
Endpoints:                10.32.0.4:443,10.32.0.5:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access the application on  ipaddress:8080 without using a proxy server in front or changing IPtable rules(not good idea). NodePort service type will always expose service in port range 30000-32767

So at any point, your service will be running on ipaddress:some_higher_port

Running a  proxy in front which, redirects the traffic to node port and since 8080 is your requirement so run proxy server also on 8080 port.

Just to add proxy server will not be part of Kubernetes  cluster

If you are on cloud consider using LoadBalancer service and access you app on some DNS name.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So if I understand correctly I can create a proxy server  in front of my raspis or using loadBalancer. Is there a way for the create LoadBalancer for a group of Raspi?

Comment: Lets say you create a deployment with 3 raspi,in front of it you can create a service which will distribute traffic to  these 3 raspi. Now this service will be accessed from outside on nodeport which is higher 30000-32767.  so you  have to create proxy in front of it

Alternatively when you create service and if you are in  cloud , make service type as loadbalancer,which will create load balancer for you automatically  and will redirect traffic to your raspi